# Send using sed with variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use the send command with a sed which uses a variable.
Having trouble to escape correctly.

```
send "sed "1i//$VAR" /file > /tmp/out\r"
```

If I use the sed command separately (which adds the $VAR text as first line of file), it works:

```
sed "1i//$VAR" /file > /tmp/out
```

But I can't figure out how to escape within the send command.

Comment: This is for `expect`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside double quotes, single quotes lose their special meaning, so you probably need:

```
send "sed '1i//$VAR' /file > /tmp/out\r"
```

On the local machine, the `$VAR` is placed into the command.  On the remote machine, the `sed` command is enclosed in single quotes, protecting it from further abuse.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
send "sed '1i//$VAR' /file > /tmp/out\r"
```

Only the type of the outermost quotes matters for determining whether variables are interpolated.